# How to implement ServletContextListener in struts2, spring, hibernate application?

Tags: spring, hibernate, servlets, struts2

In my application I want to store some of my data in ServletContext as its going to be used through out the application. Data are saved in a database. All the configurations are made through integrating struts2, spring, hibernate. Problem is that, I am finding difficulties to fetch the data from the database. Spring is unable to inject the dao impl class to the class that is implementing the ServleltContextListener. Can anyone please tell me how to do this? Or is there any alternative?

Comment: No I am extremely sorry. But if there is anyway to load the data to context fetching from the database, where application is made of struts 2, spring and hibernate. Please tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    /**
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletContextListener#contextInitialized
     * (javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent) 
     */
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        WebApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext());
        Object yourDaoImplClass = applicationContext.getBean("your_bean_name_or_bean_id");
        //You can type cast yourDaoImplClass to your object
    }

    /**
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed
     * (javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent) 
     */    
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {

    }

}
```

Hope this works. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you it works for me. I am a fool actually,  I forgot that we can get the spring beans like this too...

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu how can I use 'yourDaoImplClass' in other classes?

Comment: @Saipavan579 You can inject Spring's `ApplicationContext` in other classes and use the application context like this `@Autowire private ApplicationContext applicationContext; DAOClass dao = applicationContext.getBean("your_bean_name_or_bean_id")` or you can inject the DAOClass directly in other classes

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to implement Spring's ServletContextAware interface and then use an @PostConstruct or afterPropertiesSet method to add items to the servlet context.